# iOS app upload to app store invalid provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile, application-loader

I create certificates and all of required things from member center. And i've added keychain and xcode project. But when i try to upload my app to app store via application loader, i get error below. I've recreated certificates and provisioning profiles but doesn't work.

[image: http://i.hizliresim.com/KlDqQJ.png]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Xcode menu and select preferences. When the preference window opens click on the accounts tab. Click view details in the bottom right this brings up the profile pane. Click the refresh icon in the lower left. Sometimes you need to refresh twice. Also make sure the app I'd you entered in the publishing system matches the one you have in the profile. This works for me.

Comment: i havent tried yet, after i try, i'll write the result

Comment: i've solved my problem.i didn't use application loader, i've connected my iphone and validate from archives.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the provisioning profile in the project as per screen shot[image: Shows Project settings]

Comment: If you are seeing None, then you need to select the correct Provisioning Profile from the list, you should have one for production?

Comment: @Burak make sure you have selected the distribution profile of appstore and not the ad-hoc one.

Comment: @Flexicoder i am not seeing None, i set it as correct Provisioning Profile.